# Is it ok to copy/paste myself?

Tags: discussion, answers

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35485865/is-it-possible-to-perform-docker-call-from-a-container-into-the-host) has been asked few weeks ago. No upvote for the question, nor any feedback from the OP even my own answer (IMO) answers to OP's question.

Today, this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606093/accessing-docker-port-from-inside-docker-container/35607144#35607144) has been asked.

Is it ok to copy/paste my own answers?

Also I did not flag (yet?) the possible duplicate as the first question is not tagged as answered while I expect the second one will be as it got more attention (already two upvote ~1 h after posting).

Was I right to do so? What would had been the best practices?

Comment: If the exact same answer works for both questions, then flag it as a duplicate. If not, then you should adjust the answer accordingly for each one.

Comment: Your existing answer has 2 up votes. It doesn't have to be marked as accepted to be a duplicate target (AFAIK).

Comment: The newer question is better. I think the older question should be duplicate voted against the newer one

Comment: AFAIK, human cloning is illegal in most jurisdictions.

Comment: @resueman but the first question OP did not feedback anything. So my answer might not be _the_ answer.

Comment: @BSMP What if the newer one is tagged as anwser? Then the site may delete one answered-question in favor of a possibly unanswered one.

Comment: @Martin thanks for the laugh :)

Comment: @Auzias may as well have a bit of fun here.  With all the bad homework questions on main, it's the only feelgood factor available on SO :)